# SQL Duplicate Results

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, count

I have a query like so

```
$query =$this->db->query('SELECT COUNT(did) AS TheCount
                             FROM posts
                             GROUP BY did');

    return $query->result();
```

and that query relates to this query

```
$this->db->group_by('did')
             ->from('posts')
             ->join('users', 'users.username = posts.username');

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
```

and the problem I'm having is the HTML displays the second query perfectly but duplicates the first query within the first query if that makes any sense...

Kinda like this

```
a post | TheCount number, DifferentCount number

another post | TheCount number, DifferentCount number
```

I hope that's enough relevant information, and yes, I've already tried using `DISTINCT` on the first query.

and for some more information, each post is grouped into a discussion with the discussion having its own `id` hence `did`, and each post has its own `pid`.

I want it to look like this

```
a post | TheCount number

another post | DifferentCount number
```

and concerning performance wise, would it be better to count the number of posts using `COUNT`, or would it be better to just store the number in the database with it changing by removal, or an addition of a post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it! Took me forever, but my answer kinda comes from @Eldono, but all I did, was take his answer and put it in my first query, and just got rid of the second query entirely, of course I changed his `SELECT did` to `SELECT *`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting the 'did' in the first query, so you get unreferenced count number of posts without knowing what they refer to.

Edit:
You didn't specify what you want, you just posted the same thing again...
However I think the SQL you need is something like this:

```
SELECT did, username, COUNT(*) AS TheCount
FROM posts
JOIN users ON users.username = posts.username
GROUP BY did
```

With this query you'll get for every discussion the count of posts for every user who partecipated in that discussion.
Something like:

```
did   |   Username | TheCount
1     |   John     | 2 (posts)
1     |   Andrew   | 1 (post)
2     |   Michael  | 5
2     |   John     | 4
...
```

If you are focusing on a specific username you could simplify like this:

```
SELECT did, COUNT(*) AS TheCount
FROM posts
WHERE posts.username = 'John'
GROUP BY did
```

Result:

```
did   |   Username | TheCount
1     |   John     | 2 (posts)
2     |   John     | 4
```

If you need something different, just specify what count do you want (for every discussion? for every user? for a custom user?)

Comment: I just changed what you specified, but I still get the same result.

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you want to achieve then, could you add some more infos?

Comment: I've added some more info, maybe that will clear it up a bit.